# How do I get an absolute value in Rust?

Tags: rust

The docs are unhelpful: http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v0.9/doc/std/num/fn.abs.html

Obviously, I can see the function right there, but I haven't got the faintest idea how to call it.

Edit:

The problem is that it doesn't *work.* :)

```
use std::num;
let x = num::abs(value);
```

"Unresolved name: num::abs"

Edit 2: running the nightly from yesterday (11/26/2014); I don't know what version. I didn't realize those docs were so outdated. oO

Current docs seem to indicate there is no such function?

Comment: I still have to get my hands on rust but `std::num::abs` looks like the appropriate call .

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, too.

Comment: and what is the problem? show your code .

Comment: Those docs are for a very old version of Rust, 0.9 (it's unfortunate but we haven't been able to get in touch with whoever put them up to try to get them demoted in the search results). http://doc.rust-lang.org/std is the best place to look for documentation about the standard library of the nightly versions (there's a built-in search too). What version of Rust do you have? (`rustc -v`)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Nowadays, [`abs` is a method on most number types](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/?search=abs).

```
let value = -42i32;
let x = value.abs();
```

Comment: I don't think it matters whether you call the member method or the "global" `abs` function, either way the appropriate overload should be invoked .

Comment: @user2485710: what do you mean, ‘ “global” `abs` function’? There ain’t such a thing any more. `std::num::abs` does not exist.

Comment: well, http://play.rust-lang.org/ offers the latest rust implementation and it just works .

Comment: There seems to have been a [`std::num::abs`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/fn.abs.html) in 0.12, was it removed since ?

Comment: @user2485710: play.rust-lang.org is today three weeks out of date.

Comment: still valid against what you say, that function is there in 0.12. Are we talking about a mismatch in the master trunk considering a 3 weeks timeframe ? Either way you still have to prove that said function doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @user2485710 yes, changes have to happen at some point, it just so happens that this change occurred in the last 3 weeks. The function clearly doesn't exist or else one would not get an unresolved name error and the question wouldn't need to be asked. [You can also use the search to confirm](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/?search=abs).

Comment: This was changed to core from std, and int is gone now. Updated answer: http://is.gd/B3A6EP

Answer (score 16):

The  answer mentioning `std::num::abs` doesn't work anymore.

Instead, use:

```
i32::abs(n)
```

Comment: Other answer is more generally useful, though this answer is not wrong.
To use the other answer, you need to know you can call any method with an instance of the type as a first argument, then you can use that answer in all contexts.

Answer (score 6):

```
fn main() {
    let mut number: i32 = -8;
    number = number.abs();
    println!("{}", number);
}
```

Remember that you must specify the datatype explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
pub fn absolute_value(&self) -> i16 {
i16::abs(self.0) + i16::abs(self.1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `abs()` to work, it should already know the type of the value. If you notice in the above answers, context already determines the type of number. However, this will not work:

```
println!("{}", (-1).abs());
```

It will give error:

```
 can't call method `abs` on ambiguous numeric type
```

Because Rust wants to know exactly which integer type a value has before it calls the type’s own methods. In this case, you should

```
println!("{}", (-1_i32).abs());
println!("{}", i32::abs(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrive here after facing a similar error message when dealing with `usize` types, consider [usize::abs_diff](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.abs_diff). Although the accepted answer mentions `abs` being available for most integer types, of course `abs` is not available for unsigned integers, including `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, and `u64` because those integers are always zero or positive. Still, taking an absolute of the difference of two numbers is a common situation, for example to compare lengths of vectors or strings:

```
let diff = (vec_a.len() - vec_b.len()).abs();
// --> ERROR: no method named `abs` found
```

The difference taking is problematic for unsigned integers because the result should be able to go negative. The use of `abs_diff` avoids that caveat:

```
let a_len = word_a.len();
let b_len = word_b.len();
let diff = a_len.abs_diff(b_len);
```

Answer (score -4):

That's because you are probably not providing enough type information .

```
fn main() {
    println!("Abs is \"{}\"",
              std::num::abs(-42i));
}
```

notice the `i` suffix that tells to Rust that `-42` is an integer .

Rule of the thumb is that: you have to specify what your type is somewhere, somehow and the suffix are handy, for example another way this works is

```
fn main() {
    let x = -42i;
    println!("Abs is \"{}\"",
              std::num::abs(x));
}
```

this works too

```
fn main() { 
    let x: int = -42;
    println!("Abs is \"{}\"",
              std::num::abs(x));
}
```

if you want a mutable you just have to add `mut` right after `let`

```
fn main() { 
    let mut x: int = -42; 
    x += x;
    println!("Abs is \"{}\"",
              std::num::abs(x));
}
```

and you get `x` and you can change the value of `x` .

Comment: It's a strongly-typed language. The variable has all the type information it can possibly get.

Comment: @archer884 type inference it's not necessarily related to the fact that a language is "strong" or "weakly" typed, the rules of the game are just about providing a type which is supposed to be the right type that you want .

Comment: It's a variable. Not a constant. A constant would need the additional type info you mentioned, but we're discussing a variable. That's clear in the code sample you requested. You can't decorate a variable. You add an 'i' after a variable name and you just change the name. Doesn't help.

Comment: @archer884 added another example, it's just a matter of adding 1 keyword .