# Is there a way to tell rust to choose the positive number if they are equal closest to zero (ex: -2 0 2) => 2

Tags: rust

If there are two numbers equal closest to zero (-2 0 2), I want to return the positive number.

```
let y = x.iter().min_by_key(|&num| ( num - given_num).abs()).unwrap_or(&given_num);
```

This prints only the closest value to 0, but doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get an absolute value in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182808/how-do-i-get-an-absolute-value-in-rust)

Comment: I am not familiar with Rust. However, using large ternary statements make things complicated to understand. Why not having multiple lines of code?

Comment: Does your list have only 3 items? can there be more than one positive number? what if there is no positive numbers? should it select the zero or the closest negative? What does it choose if the numbers are -1, 0, 2?

Comment: Given that the OP already calls `abs` properly in the question, I'd say that the duplicate has nothing to do with the question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust can compare tuples, so you can return a tuple in the `min_by_key` closure to prioritize results that would otherwise be equal:

```
let y = x.iter()
         .min_by_key (|&num| ((num - given_num).abs(), -num.signum()))
         .unwrap_or (&given_num);
```

Comment: Thank you Jmb :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: First filter out the zero, then use fold to compare minimum absolute values. If both are the same, use the max between the real values.

```
use std::cmp;
use std::i32;

fn main() {
    let x: Vec<i32> = vec![-2, 0, 2];
    let y = x
        .iter()
        .filter(|&i| *i != 0)
        .fold(i32::MAX, |n, &i| {
            if n.abs() < i.abs() {
                n
            } else if n.abs() == i.abs() {
                cmp::max(n, i)
            } else {
                i
            }
        });
    println!("{:}", y);
}
```